# How to get literal value of JS object key

Tags: javascript, string, javascript-objects, string-literals

I'm communicating with an Active Directory which responds with, for example, user parameters. Among those parameters are the CN and DN. As the structure of this DN can be variable from system to system, I need to come up with a general solution.

The problem I'm facing is when the DN is returned with double backslashes, like this:

```
User:  { 
  dn: 'CN=LastName\\, SurName,OU=People,DC=COMP,DC=NL',
  cn: 'LastName, Surname' 
}
```

When I then request all groups this user belongs to, this fails. When I try to access the key 'dn' of this object, the double backslashes are automatically parsed to a single backslash. Like this:

```
User dn:  CN=LastName\, SurName,OU=People,DC=COMP,DC=NL
```

And this does not give back any results because the members are stored in the AD with double backslash.

I need a generic way to take the value of the object-key in literal form, without JavaScript parsing the escape characters.

The following forms can also occur inside the AD system for the DN:

```
DN: CN=LastName\\, SurName,OU=People,DC=COMP,DC=NL
DN: CN=LastName\, SurName,OU=People,DC=COMP,DC=NL
DN: CN=Surname LastName,OU=People,DC=COMP,DC=NL
DN: CN=LastName SurName,OU=People,DC=COMP,DC=NL
```

I already tried String.raw, escape(), JSON.stringify, but all those result in invalid DN's which I can paste in the search query for the groups of a user.

**Update**
As pointed out in the replies I wasn't completely thorough in my explaination.
So the return object as depicted above is correct, that is what is returned from the AD via LDAP search (searched for a user first).

It is then injected in the function that requests all the groups for that specific user while not modifying or touching the object and the filter is constructed the following manner (where ldapUser is the object from above):

```
const opts = {
    filter: `(&(objectClass=group)(member=${ldapUser.dn}))`,
    scope: "sub",
    attributes: ["dn", "cn"],
};
```

I'm using the ldapjs package by the way on NodeJS v10.15.3.
The resulting filter when printed is then:

```
filter:  (&(objectClass=group)(member=CN=LastName\, SurName,OU=People,DC=COMP,DC=NL))
```

**Update 2**
So here is the requested output of various console.log statements:

```
console.log(ldapUser.dn, opts.filter);
CN=LastName\, SurName,OU=People,DC=COMP,DC=NL (&(objectClass=group)(member=CN=LastName\, SurName,OU=People,DC=COMP,DC=NL))

console.log(ldapUser, ldapUser.dn, opts.filter);
{ dn: 'CN=LastName\\, SurName,OU=People,DC=COMP,DC=NL',
  controls: [],
  cn: 'LastName, SurName' } 'CN=LastName\\, SurName,OU=People,DC=COMP,DC=NL' '(&(objectClass=group)(member=CN=LastName\\, SurName,OU=People,DC=COMP,DC=NL))'

console.log(opts);
{ 
filter: '(&(objectClass=group)(member=CN=LastName\\, SurName,OU=People,DC=COMP,DC=NL))',
  scope: 'sub',
  attributes: [ 'dn', 'cn' ] 
}
```

Comment: If AD returns a string with value `CN=LastName\\, SurName,OU=People,DC=COMP,DC=NL` then the double backslashes will NOT be interpreted as a single backslash. Only string literals will try to interpret backslashes as escape sequences - the *value* of a string is the result after this interpretation has taken place. If there is no string literal, then there is no interpretation - a string with value `\n` will have the literal value `\n` not a new line, regardless of how you pass it around.

Comment: @VLAZ only string literals... and JSON parse. Similarly, JSON stringification done manually could miss the mandatory doubling of backslashes. We have no code to inspect, we do not know which protocol is used, so it is very hard to know what is going on.

Comment: @Amadan yeah, there is also JSON.parse which will do a second interpretation of the string value. But if *that* fails, then AD fails to properly send the values in the first place, since it needs to escape the backslashes.

Comment: String.raw seems to be a good bet. What did you try that failed how?

Comment: @VLAZ: All I'm saying is, while what you stated is literally true (slashes don't randomly appear or disappear unless something makes them do so, and usually people have problems with interpretation of literals or inspected values), _something_ is obviously going wrong (or the question wouldn't have been asked); and the only way to get to the bottom of it is to know more about what is happening.

Comment: @Amadan: I've updated the question with additional relevant information, my apologises for not being complete in my description.

Comment: So... we still don't know how exactly you're inspecting `User` and `filter`; so for clarity, what is the console output of `console.log(ldapUser.dn, opts.filter)`?

Comment: @Amadan I'm sorry I misunderstood, I've updated again :)

Comment: As your logs clearly show, `dn` only has a single backslash. Printing out an entire object doubles it _in display only_, as it shows JSON (where backslash must be escaped).

Comment: @Amadan Oh I actually didn't think about this, clearly :) As you now mention it, it makes sense :) Using your questions and answers I was able to solve it really simple with a replace action on the backslash :) Thanks !